# Где именно надо в FORTRAN писать директиву OpenMP "THREADPRIVATE" для common-блоков и SAVE-переменных?

Tags: многопоточность, openmp, fortran

Скажите, пожалуйста, где именно надо размещать директиву OpenMp THREADPRIVATE для common-блока? Сразу после описания этого блока, сразу после описания этого блока и всех остальных любых переменных или же только после всех блоков DATA? Приведу пример:

```
SUBROUTINE SCHNEVPDH (RZ,FLAT,FLON,R,T,L,BN,BE,BV)
      PARAMETER   (IBO=0,JBO=1,KDIM=8,LDIM=4)
      DIMENSION   FN(0:KDIM,0:KDIM), CONSTP(0:KDIM,0:KDIM)
      DIMENSION   CML(KDIM), SML(KDIM)
      DIMENSION   DELT(0:LDIM)
      DIMENSION   BINT(0:KDIM,0:KDIM,1-IBO-JBO:LDIM),
     *            BEXT(0:KDIM,0:KDIM,1-IBO-JBO:LDIM)
      COMMON    /CONST/UMR,PI
     *          /AMTB/BINT,BEXT,RE,TZERO,IFIT,IB,KINT,LINT,KEXT,
     *              LEXT,KMAX,FN
      CHARACTER*1 IE,RESP
      DATA ((CONSTP(N,M), M=0,N), N=0,KDIM)
     *   /4*1.,1.73205,0.866025,1.,2.44949,1.93649,0.7905691,1.,
     *    3.16228,3.35410,2.09165,0.739510,1.,3.87298,5.12348,
     *    4.18330,2.21853,0.701561,1.,4.58258,2*7.24569,4.96078,
     *      2.32681,0.671693,1.,5.29150,9.72111,11.4564,9.49918,
     *      5.69951,2.42182,0.647260,1.,6.,12.5499,16.9926,16.4531,
     *      11.8645,6.40755,2.50683,0.626707/
!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(/CONST/)
!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(/AMTB/)
      IBF   =  2
      T1=1.
      T2=12.
      CALL TBFIT (T1,T2,IBF,THINT,TZERO)
```

В правильном ли месте я здесь разместил данную директиву? Такой же вопрос — применительно к переменным типа SAVE.